# Laravel seed for dateTime doesnt'work

Tags: php, laravel, seed

I have migration table :

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('order_statuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('status_id')->unsigned();
        $table->dateTime('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));

        $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders');
        $table->foreign('status_id')->references('id')->on('order_status_names');
    });
}
```

Now i would like to make seed but I have seeds for this but I have problem  when I want to have different dates. Here is my seeds :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class OrderStatusesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
public function run()
{
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');
    DB::table('order_statuses')->truncate();
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');

    DB::table('order_statuses')->insert([
            [
                'order_id' => 1,
                'status_id' => 1,
                'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate(2014,07,22)->toDateTimeString()
            ],[
                'order_id' => 2,
                'status_id' => 2,
            ],[
                'order_id' => 3,
                'status_id' => 3,
            ],[
                'order_id' => 1,
                'status_id' => 2,
            ]
        ]
    );
}
}
```

I have error in my terminal :

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 
Column   
count doesn't match value count at row 2 (SQL: insert into 
`order_statuses`  
(`created_at`, `order_id`, `status_id`) values (2014-07-22 11:32:07, 
1, 1)  
, (2, 2), (3, 3), (1, 2))
```

Is here a possibility to fix it? Carbon is in LAravel or I have to install this?

Comment: You're getting that error because your arrays are different i.e. you have `created_at` in your first array but not in the rest of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list

Means you are passing wrong number of argument for last three rows:

```
DB::table('order_statuses')->insert(
    [
        [
            'order_id' => 1,
            'status_id' => 1,
            'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate(2014,07,22)->toDateTimeString()
        ],[
            'order_id' => 2,
            'status_id' => 2,
            'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate(2014,07,22)->toDateTimeString()
        ],[
            'order_id' => 3,
            'status_id' => 3,
            'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate(2014,07,22)->toDateTimeString()
        ],[
            'order_id' => 1,
            'status_id' => 2,
            'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate(2014,07,22)->toDateTimeString()
        ]
    ]
);
```

You can pass `null` as value for `created_at` if column allow for nullable.